# Measure performance using SeleniumWebDriver vs native javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Let's assume that some action is performed when I click the button on a web-page. Let's say it takes **X** seconds and during these seconds a `div` is displayed in the center of the page. When action processing is finished the `div` is removed and focus goes to element **E**.

1) I've written a test in **Selenium ( C# )**:

```
stopwatch.Restart();
button.Click();
while (driver.FindElementsById(PopupDivId).Count != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
stopwatch.Stop();
```

2 ) And a test in javascript (inside my page). Simplified code:

**OnClick button handler:**

```
console.time('test');
```

**GotFocus handler on textbox (element E):**

```
console.log(document.getElementById('My_PopupDivId')); // just to be sure - it returns null
console.timeEnd('test');
```

---

For some reason Selenium measurements are ~2x bigger than direct javascript measurements.
(400ms vs 800ms).

Is this something wrong with my code or it's just Selenium inaccuracy ( does it actually make sense to measure such things as javascript/DOM performance using Selenium?)

Comment: It's not inaccuracy in Selenium.  You are comparing apples and oranges.  When talking with Firefox, you are asking a remote process for some information, where as in javascript, you are just reading the DOM from memory.

Comment: I know this, by `inaccuracy` I mean that Selenium is slow enough to produce x2 milliseconds compared to js. Currenty investigating performance of `FindElementsById` and it seems like it's really slow...

Comment: Overall, it seems strange to me that people are using Selenium for performance tests if it's so slow, 400ms margin is OMG, measurement does not make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Koerner's comment is right on the money. You are comparing apples and oranges. Here are some factors affecting the difference:

1. Selenium uses a wire protocol to talk to your browser. It has to take your parameters, marshal them, send them to the browser, wait for a response, unmarshal the return value and give it to your code. That's in *addition* to whatever DOM operations are performed.
2. Your Selenium timing include the click operation as part of what is timed, whereas you start your JavaScript timing **inside** the event handler for the click. Selenium does some housekeeping work when you ask it to click on a button, like for instance check whether it is visible and bring it in to view if it is not visible. Your Selenium timing includes the cost of this, but your JavaScript timing does not.
3. Your Selenium code is subject to whatever implicit wait value is set. I don't typically use implicit wait but I've just tested it and found that if I ask Selenium for a list of elements, it will wait until the implicit wait has elapsed before telling me there are none.

To get a better idea of how much Selenium is affecting your results, you should try your test with different delays between the appearance of the `div` and its removal. I really doubt that a case where your JavaScript timing would yield 2 seconds would translate to a 4 second timing in Selenium.

As for using Selenium for performance measurements, I'd say Selenium is a **very blunt** tool for such task. When I'm worried about code performance in a browser, I skip Selenium and use JavaScript directly. I have used Selenium to get an idea about performance, in the *aggregate*. For instance, there's been times I reworked some core part of an application and then ran a test suite that uses Selenium and found the time to run the whole test suite significantly improved. However, as I said, this is blunt. We're talking seconds of difference, not milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks! I have set all implicit waits to 0, so that point is not the case, but as for the rest I agree with you and this corresponds to my observations. (PS: 2s won't transalate to 4s, but i deal with <1s durations)